# expected ',' or '...' before 'struct' error

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, struct

Good day,

I have the first time this kind of error.

```
// another.h
struct Item {
  QString name = QString();
  QString description = QString();
  QVariant value = QVariant();
  struct Interface {
    uint id = 0;
    uint pos = 0;
  } mkio, uks;
  struct Element {
    float weight = 0;
    struct Range {
      uint from = 0;
      uint to = 0;
    } range;
  int index = 0;
} element;
};
```

I would like to store this nested struct in a stream. So,

```
// another.h
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Item::Interface &interface)
{
  return out << interface.id
             << interface.pos;
}
// and another overload operator>> and operator<<...
// Another fields of the `Item` struct are compiling without any error.
```

1) error: expected ',' or '...' before 'struct'
 QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Item::Interface &interface)

2) another.h:34:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
return out << interface.id
                ^
another.h:34:17: error: expected ';' before 'struct'
another.h:34:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Seems that you have some problems with declaration order. Or you forgot to include QDataStream header. Btw, your code is unreadable, try to avoid such nested declarations of structures.

Comment: can you tag line at wich errors happend

Comment: `};` - the last line - what is it?

Comment: To Dmitry: first define struct then overload operator. I included QDataStream. Reordering struct and define `Interface` has no result...

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in the code, most likely in a library header, the following (or something very similar to it) is hiding:

```
#define interface struct
```

which makes the compiler see this:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Item::Interface &struct)
{
  return out << struct.id
             << struct.pos;
}
```

and become very upset.

Rename the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found the wrong place it is the name of variable “interface" (from the small letter).
Renaming it to the `i`, for example clear the code.

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Item::Interface &i /*nterface*/)
```

The type `Interface` declared in a namespace so change its name hadn't the result.